# Forgot IE password for parental controls on windows vista

Tags: windows-vista, internet-explorer, passwords, parental-controls

A good friend of mine has 3 kids. He was very worried about protecting his kids from porn, so in a panic, he turned on Parental Controls. His mistake was that he entered a password and did not write it down. He did not use the laptop for a week after setting the password. It was just some number that he can no longer remember. Now that he wants to accually use the laptop, he can not open most of the pages he wants to visit (NON-PORN).

Is there a was to reset the password or turn it off?
He only has IE on his laptop. Would Firefox used the same controls?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove the setting from the registry.  Check out [this post on how](http://www.intelliadmin.com/blog/2007/11/ie-parental-controls-how-to-remove-them.html).  Basically, this the Ratings key here ...

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System
```

Comment: This of course makes Microsoft's client side internet filter useless against a determined teenager. The best defence is to supervise your children's internet activities and teach them what is and isn't acceptable.

Comment: Well, you shouldn't really be allowing your teenager to be running as admin on the box.  If you do, it's just a battle of obfuscation.  But, Vista and Windows 7 make that much easier to accomplish and still allow a good experience.

Comment: I agree 100%.  "The best defence is to supervise your children's internet activities and teach them what is and isn't acceptable." However, I feel the parental controls provide some "additional" benefit. It would be stupid to ONLY trust parental controls. I think I will start a wiki on this subject. Thanks.